# inputrc: menu-complete-backward doesn't work on Mac OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, readline

My `.inputrc` is exactly the same on my linux box as it is on my macbook pro, running Yosemite:

```
Control-n: menu-complete
Control-p: menu-complete-backward
```

On Linux, it works flawlessly; however, on my macbook pro, only `Control-n` works, but `Control-p` doesn't cycle backward or do anything.  In fact, `menu-complete-backward` doesn't even get highlighted as proper syntax when I'm editing the `inputrc`.  Is it a Darwin thing, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type the `cat` command, and press Ctrl+P, what escape sequence do you see? (I see `^P`)

I tried to bind `Shift+Tab` to `menu-complete-backward` and only this binding worked for me:

```
"\e[Z": "\e-1\C-i"
```

So Ctrl+P should be:

```
Control-p: "\e-1\C-i"
```

From http://brettterpstra.com/2011/09/25/quick-tip-some-inputrc-fun/

EDIT: Note that `menu-complete-backward` is only supported for bash > 4.0.0, and Yosemite has Bash 3.2.57. [This upgrade procedure](https://superuser.com/questions/857250/how-to-update-bash-on-mac-os-x-yosemite) worked for me, also see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24635).

Comment: When I put this in my `.inputrc`, `^P` seems to just show all my possibilities.

Comment: I think this is related to `show-all-if-ambiguous`. Try to use `set show-all-if-ambiguous off`. Another thing might be related is `show-all-if-unmodified`.

Comment: I think I found the problem.  I read [a small snippet](https://github.com/netj/dotfiles/blob/master/.inputrc) just a second ago that said menu-complete-backward is only supported in bash > 4.0.0.  OS X Yosemite by default ships with Bash 3.2.57.  Put this in your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Just for clarity - `"\e-1\C-i"` is a pre-bash 4.0 alternative to `menu-complete-backward`, doing this now you'd use `"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward`.

Comment: What is this encoding called, where as an example "\e[Z" equals "Control-p"?

Comment: In `~/.bash_profile` use: `bind TAB:menu-complete` and `bind '"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward'` (note the usage of single and double quotes!).